# UISplitViewController and CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on a project that uses CoreData one-to-many relationship between folder and files. To show this I am using UISplitViewController, Folders are shown on MasterView and on click of each folder the files are shown on DetailView.Both folders and files are added dynamically.

I have programatically created UISPlitViewController this way

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

       FolderViewController = [[FolderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FolderViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];


        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:FolderViewController];
        FolderViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

        fileViewController = [[fileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"fileViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: fileViewController];

        FolderViewController.fileViewController = fileViewController;

        self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
        self.splitViewController.delegate = fileViewController;
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

}
```

This splits my ipad in to two. Leftside is FolderViewController and rightside is FileViewController.

My master View never hides, in any Orientation.

I have  a button on both Master and DetailView which opens common EditViewController modally through splitViewController this way

```
- (void)Buttonclick
{

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];       
        testViewController = [[EditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditViewController" bundle:nil];
        m_editViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

        [appDelegate.splitViewController presentModalViewController:m_editViewController animated:YES];
}
```

and when I dismiss this View, I add folders or files accordingly.

I dismiss this view this way

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I have few doubts here

1) When I launch the app, all imp(main) functions from Both View Controller gets called.is that ok?

2) When I dismiss this ModalView when opened from DetailView, the delegate functions of NSFetchResultsController get called, which are in MasterView . is that ok?

3) As those functions are getting called, my logic fails in some situations.

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Point 1) in your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: What are the main functions of the view controllers? Do you mean they are both created and have 'init...' called on them?

Comment: I meant ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear.

Comment: Those methods are called automatically by the framework, it's expected that they are called as the view is loaded and displayed.

Comment: ok, So those functions are called because both views are loaded at the same time right?